# Emulator crashes with lost connection to device while trying to read pdf

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, pdf

I have a following screen, that gets a pdf or file from the next page. But when I try to read PDF, the emulator crashes with 'Lost Connection to Device' and following error. I am using advanced_pdf_viewer for reading the pdf. This issue is only with android and not ios

Error : I/System.out( 5829): Already closed
W/System.err( 5829): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already closed
D/PdfViewerPlugin( 5829): Retrieving page failed.
D/AndroidRuntime( 5829): Shutting down VM
E/flutter ( 5829): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPage on channel flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer)

```
class FilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilePage({this.file, this.isImage = false});
  final FirebaseFile? file;
  final isImage;
  @override
  _FilePageState createState() => _FilePageState();
}

class _FilePageState extends State<FilePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final isPdf = ['.pdf', 'pdf', '.PDF', 'PDF'].any(file.name.contains);
    //final isEpub = ['.epub'].any(file.name.contains);
    // final isImg = ['.jpg', '.JPG', '.png', '.PNG', '.jpeg', '.JPEG']
    //   .any(file.name.contains);
    //  int _totalPages=0;
    //   int _currentPage=0;
    //   bool pdfReady=false;
    //   PDFViewController _pdfViewController;

    //initState(){
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => true,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
          title: Text(widget.file!.name.split('.').first),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: PDFDocument.fromURL(widget.file!.url),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                default:
                  var pdf = snapshot.data as PDFDocument;
                  return PDFViewer(document: pdf);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: It did not work for me

Comment: I think the issue is with the plugin. Try using different version and try again.

Comment: works well with ios.Issue is only with android

Comment: Is there an issue with the emulator you are using.?, Try in another emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the real problem behind this but you can try these simple steps.

1. `flutter clean` (in terminal)
2. Restart your code editor
3. `pub get` (in terminal)
4. Cold boot your emulator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).